# How to get the value of selectOneMenu by using clientId in Javascript Method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I have a datatable which contains selectOneMenu. I want to get selected value of selectOneMenu in my Javascript method by using clientId. I have tried with this following code..

```
 <p:dataTable var="name" value="#{model.nameList}" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">
<p:selectOneMenu id="selector_#{rowIndex}" onchange="select(#{rowIndex});">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue=""></f:selectItem>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Month" itemValue="Month"></f:selectItem>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Week" itemValue="Week"></f:selectItem>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
</p:dataTable>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function select(rowIndex){
        selector = "selector_" + rowIndex;
        var element = $("select[name$=" + selector +" option:selected").val();

        alert(element);
    }
</script>
```

---

I need two values in javascript method, rowIndex and the selected value of selectOneMenu

Comment: please show the generated markup of your jsp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" template="/WEB-INF/templates/globalTemplate.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="title">15320268</ui:define>
    <ui:define name="content">
        <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />

        <h:form>
            <p:dataTable var="name" value="#{so15320268.nameList}" rowIndexVar="rowIndex" widgetVar="table">                
                <p:column>
                    <p:selectOneMenu widgetVar="menu_#{rowIndex}" onchange="select(menu_#{rowIndex});">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue=""></f:selectItem>
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Month" itemValue="Month"></f:selectItem>
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Week" itemValue="Week"></f:selectItem>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function select(widgetVar){
                var selectMenuDiv = widgetVar.getJQ(); // it will give you the underlying jquery object
                //alert(selectMenuDiv.get(0)); // uncoment this line it will show: [object HTMLDivElement]; 
                // so it is not select element
                var selectMenu = $(selectMenuDiv).find('select');
                var selectValue = $('> option:selected', selectMenu).val();
                alert(selectValue);             
            }
        </script>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Look into the following image, this is how `<p:selectOneMenu/>` renders:
[image]

Look carefully at the id of highlighted div. It ends with `selector_`. The xhtml was: `<p:selectOneMenu id="selector_#{rowIndex}"`. You were trying to create id with el and in JSF which is not allowed, that is why the `#{rowIndex}` didn't rendered for id. The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/) says that id must be evaluated to `java.lang.String` if it does support el then this would be

> javax.el.ValueExpression(must evaluate to java.lang.String)

Probably the the reason is in the method `public void setValueExpression(String name, ValueExpression binding)` of `javax.faces.component.UIComponent` has `if (!(binding.isLiteralText()))`.

I hope it will help you to understand the el cannot be used in id.

Comment: But how can I get value from widgetVar?

Comment: What value you want to get? You can get the jquery object from `widgetVar`. After that do whatever you want to do.

Comment: The selected value in selectOneMenu and the row index.

Comment: I tried to get value from your code but I am not able to get it.

Comment: @KushSahu what is not working? I have updated my code. Previously I wasn't in front of my workstation, that's why the code that I have given you was untested. The above code is working.

Comment: Hmmm you are right. Thanks for such nice brief explanation. I was not aware that el cant be used for id. Now I am clear about it. I also found that in your answer, that index of row is included in rendered id. See in Id :0:Selector_ .Right now I am not able to test your code since I am away from my workstation. But as I have tested my code, in :0:Selector_ I think 0 is row index. Its not by #rowIndex but still its a row index. By some how we can also use that for purpose like mine. Isn't it??

Comment: @KushSahu The 0, 1, 2 etc these are generated by the Primefaces which is similar to rowIndex, you are right, its nothing but the index of the list currently the `dataTable` is pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

add a class to your select

```
<p:dataTable var="name" value="#{model.nameList}" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">
<p:selectOneMenu styleClass="myClass" id="selector_#{rowIndex}" data-rowindex="#{rowIndex}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue=""></f:selectItem>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Month" itemValue="Month"></f:selectItem>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Week" itemValue="Week"></f:selectItem>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
</p:dataTable>
```

and the js part

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(function(){
  $(".myClass").change(function(e){
   console.log($(this).val());
   console.log($(this).attr("data-rowindex"));
   //or
   //console.log($(this).data('rowindex'));
  });
 });

</script>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cCbxX/)

Comment: Hi your solution is working. But I need rowIndex for some other component which I have passed in javascript method.

Comment: i have update the answer, save the row index in a data-* attrib and access it in the change event handler

Comment: console.log($(this).attr("data-rowindex"));
I have take this as  alert($(this).attr("data-rowindex"));
but this is giving output as undefined. Also I checked p:selectOneMenu this componenet dont have data-rowindex attribute.

Comment: have you defined the data-rowindex in your primefaces defination i have posted a demo, make sure you put a custom attrib in primefaces selecOneMenu like ` data-rowindex="#{rowIndex}"`

Comment: I tried to put data-rowindex  in my selectOneMenu, but its not giving any value to javascript. I think just putting attribute will not work. I think to make changes in primefaces I have to do something. Since I am beginner I dont know how to do it. I will try that.

Comment: were you getting the rowIndex value in your code inside the javascript function?

Comment: Ya by passing rowIndex to my javascript method  I can use rowindex there.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using styleClass. Now I am able to get both selected value and the rowIndex inside javascript method.

```
<p:dataTable var="name" value="#{model.nameList}" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">
<p:column>
<p:selectOneMenu id="selector_#{rowIndex}" styleClass="menu_#{rowIndex}" onchange="select('#{rowIndex}');">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue=""></f:selectItem>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Month" itemValue="Month"></f:selectItem>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Week" itemValue="Week"></f:selectItem>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
</p:column>
</p:dataTable>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function select(rowIndex){
        var menuClassName = "menu_" + rowIndex;
        var element = $("select[class$='" + menuClassName + "'] option:selected").val(); 

    }
</script>
```

But as according to my question I am still not able to get this functioanality using clientId